# JScrollPane in Netbeans: insert corner component

Tags: netbeans, jscrollpane

`JScrollPane`s can have little components in their empty corners (between scrollbars). Coding by hand, you would use the method declared as:

> public void setCorner(String key, Component corner)

providing a string identifying which corner, and the corner componet itself.

When designing the `JFrame` via Netbeans GUI editor, is there a way to add such component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code manually by right clicking on the component and choosing `Customize Code` from the context menu.

When the Code Customizer dialog appears just add your code below the component's initializer.

Comment: ok, i already know this. so the answer is "no", it doesn't manage JScrollPane corners :-)

Comment: Actually, the answer to your question: "When designing the JFrame via Netbeans GUI editor, is there a way to add such component?" is yes, and this answer is one way to do this. You should edit your question so others will know that you are aware of this technique.